# Does sin(integer) series repeat itself?

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometry, trigonometric-series

sin(1) = 0.84, sin(2) = 0.9, sin(3) = 0.14............sin(314)=0.15...and so on..

I need to find an integer after which sin series starts repeating itself for subsequent integers. I need this as I want to create series as sin(x+RANDOM) where RANDOM is a random number and I would choose this random number from the range where this series starts repeating.

Does sin(integer) series repeat itself after any interval?

Comment: It does not because the period $2\pi$ is irrational.

Answer (score 1):

As you are working in radians, there is no integer where $\sin(x)$ starts repeating for subsequent integers. However if you are able to work in degrees, then the sequence starts repeating right from the beginning, with period $360^{\circ}$. So $\sin(0^{\circ})=\sin(360^{\circ})$.

Comment: This is true, but an angle in radians is identical to its numerical value, degrees are not. E.g. $360^\circ=2\pi$ (where the right side is identical to the resulting real number). Of course, this is because that's how the angular measurement and trig function systems are defined / set up. It could have been set up so that $360^\circ=360$, but it isn't. So $\sin(1^\circ)=\sin(2\pi)$ and $\sin(1)$ means specifically sine of 1 radian (i.e. sine of the number 1).

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Of course sin(x) without an angle means radians not degrees. I was trying to explore around the problem in order to be helpful to the questioner. I have changed my answer to clarify my meaning.